# Table content does not have fixed position

Tags: html, css

I have my table generated dynamically. I have one issue.

I every row I have edit button. On click event it is changed by Save and Cancel button.
This causes my table content of the row to move left and right.

How can I fix that?

```
<table id="settings-table" class="table table-condensed">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="text-center">Key</th>
         <th class="text-center">Value</th>
         <th class="text-center">Commands</th>
      </tr>
      {% for setting in settings %}
      <input type="hidden" class="setting_id" value="{{ setting.id }}">
      <tr>
         <td class="text-center">
            <span class="key"> {{ setting.key }} </span>
            <input type="text" id="keyEdit" class="keyEdit text-center" value="{{ setting.key }}" style="display: none">
            <p style="color: red" id="key-error"></p>
         </td>
         <td class="text-center">
            <span class="value"> {{ setting.value }} </span>
            <input type="text" id="valueEdit" class="valueEdit text-center" value="{{ setting.value }}" style="display: none">
            <p style="color: red" id="value-error"></p>
         </td>
         <td class="td-actions text-center">
            <a id="edit" class="btn btn-warning edit">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>
            </a>
            <a id="save" class="btn btn-success save" style="display: none">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>
            </a>
            <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger cancel" style="display: none">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table cells determine their width by their content. So if you want the last table cell to always have the same size, you must give it a fixed width.

Something like this:

```
<table id="settings-table" class="table table-condensed">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th class="text-center">Key</th>
         <th class="text-center">Value</th>
         <th class="text-center">Commands</th>
      </tr>
      {% for setting in settings %}
      <input type="hidden" class="setting_id" value="{{ setting.id }}">
      <tr>
         <td class="text-center">
            <span class="key"> {{ setting.key }} </span>
            <input type="text" id="keyEdit" class="keyEdit text-center" value="{{ setting.key }}" style="display: none">
            <p style="color: red" id="key-error"></p>
         </td>
         <td class="text-center">
            <span class="value"> {{ setting.value }} </span>
            <input type="text" id="valueEdit" class="valueEdit text-center" value="{{ setting.value }}" style="display: none">
            <p style="color: red" id="value-error"></p>
         </td>
         <td class="td-actions text-center" style="width: 20%">
            <a id="edit" class="btn btn-warning edit">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil"></i>
            </a>
            <a id="save" class="btn btn-success save" style="display: none">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>
            </a>
            <a id="cancel" class="btn btn-danger cancel" style="display: none">
            <i class="fa fa-fw fa-close"></i>
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Could you please set the question as answered? Thanks!